# Is this a right way to check pandigital number upto 9?

Tags: python-3.x

While solving problem 32 of project eular, I made this function to check pandigital number, is this a right way to check pandigital number? I think there is some problem, but I can't figure out it myself.

```
def pandigital(number, digit): # digit: n-digit pandigital number
    l = ['{}'.format(j) for j in [i for i in range(1,digit+1)]]
    g = list(str(number))
    g.sort()
    if g == l:
      return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a problem. In fact, three of them.

First, if a number contains more than one digit of the same denomination (duplicates), then `g` is not equal to `l` because `l` has only one copy of each digit. You should convert `l` and `g` to sets before the comparison.

Second, your function does not return anything if the number is not pandigital.

Finally, `range(1,digit+1)` does not include 0 (unless you want *zeroless* pandigital numbers).

Consider the following solution:

```
def pandigital(number, digit)
    return {f'{i}' for i in range(digit)} == set(str(number))
```

Replace `f'{i}'` with `'{}'.format(i)` if you want to stick to more "classical" Python.